# calculating length of episodes/event using R

Tags: r

I am just wondering if anyone would be able to advise me how should I approach about the following calculation with r please?

I have a hourly dataset for a year with 3 columns, "`date`" "`time`" and "`values`"

for example:

```
'01/01/2000'     '08:00'     '10'     
'01/01/2000'     '09:00'     '30'
'01/01/2000'     '10:00'     '43'
'01/01/2000'     '11:00'     '55'
'01/01/2000'     '12:00'     '59'
'01/01/2000'     '13:00'     '45'
'01/01/2000'     '14:00'     '10'
'01/01/2000'     '15:00'     '15'
'01/01/2000'     '16:00'     '43'
'01/01/2000'     '17:00'     '45'
'01/01/2000'     '18:00'     '60'
'01/01/2000'     '19:00'     '10'
```

I would like to create a data.frame that would calculate the length of episodes with values > 40, and if possible show it with the start date and time, for example from the above table 1st occurence of exceedence is at 10:00am for the duration of 4 hours and the 2nd occurance is at 16:00 for the duration of 3 hours, so I am wondering if it is possible to create a data frame as below?

```
     'date'      'time'    'Duration'  
'01/01/2000'     '10:00'       '4'
'01/01/2000'     '16:00'       '3'
```

and so on for the yearly dataset

Comment: Thanks Paul, I am very new to this website so just wondering how did you organise them in columns? I tried to insert gaps between columns but it didn't work, but yours look very neat, thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option:

```
dat <- structure(list(date = c("01/01/2000", "01/01/2000", "01/01/2000", 
  "01/01/2000", "01/01/2000", "01/01/2000", "01/01/2000", "01/01/2000", 
  "01/01/2000", "01/01/2000", "01/01/2000", "01/01/2000"), 
  time = c("08:00", "09:00", "10:00", "11:00", "12:00", "13:00", "14:00", 
  "15:00", "16:00", "17:00", "18:00", "19:00"), value = c("10", "30", "43", 
  "55", "59", "45", "10", "15", "43", "45", "60", "10")), 
  .Names = c("date", "time", "values"), row.names = c(NA, -12L), 
  class = "data.frame")

run <- rle(dat$value > 40)
dat$exceeds <- rep(run$values, run$lengths)
dat$duration <- rep(run$lengths, run$lengths)
starts <- dat[head(c(1, cumsum(run$length) + 1), length(run$length)),]
result <- subset(starts, duration > 1 & exceeds)

result[, c(1, 2, 5)]

        date  time duration
3 01/01/2000 10:00        4
9 01/01/2000 16:00        3
```

Comment: hi, thanks for you reply, unfortunately I keep getting this error "Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'exceeds' not found", but I am sure I am doing something wrong, don't worry the first answers sutes me more but thanks for trying to help me, Ayan

Answer (score 4):

Here is another solution, that relies on `plyr`:
it makes it easier to compute other quantities 
on each spell of values above 40, e.g., the average or the maximum.

```
# Sample data
k <- 3
d <- data.frame( 
  date = rep( seq.Date( Sys.Date(), length=k, by="day" ), each=24 ),
  time = sprintf( "%02d:00", rep( 0:23, k ) ),
  value = round(200*runif(24*k))
)
d$timestamp <- as.POSIXct( paste( d$date, d$time ) )
d <- d[ order( d$timestamp ), ]
# Extract the spells above 40
n <- nrow(d)
d$inside <- d$value > 40
d$start  <- ! c(FALSE, d$inside[-n]) & d$inside
d$end    <- d$inside & ! c(d$inside[-1], FALSE)  # Not used
d$group  <- cumsum(d$start)  # Number the spells
d <- d[ d$inside, ]
library(plyr)
ddply( d, "group", summarize,
  start  = min(timestamp),
  end    = max(timestamp),
  length = length(value),
  mean   = mean(value)
)
```

The spells of values above 40 can span several days: 
this may or may not be what you want.

Comment: Thanks Vincent for your reply, I have tested this answer also but for some reason its not working, keep giving me an error message, I am new to R so may be I am missing something which is causing this error, the message I get is  "Error in seq.Date(Sys.Date(), length = k, by = "day") : 'length.out' must be of length 1", but thanks for your offer to help me. I really appreciate.

Answer (score 3):

SOME DATA

```
txt <- "'01/01/2000'     '08:00'     '10'     
'01/01/2000'     '09:00'     '30'
'01/01/2000'     '10:00'     '43'
'01/01/2000'     '11:00'     '55'
'01/01/2000'     '12:00'     '59'
'01/01/2000'     '13:00'     '45'
'01/01/2000'     '14:00'     '10'
'01/01/2000'     '15:00'     '15'
'01/01/2000'     '16:00'     '43'
'01/01/2000'     '17:00'     '45'
'01/01/2000'     '18:00'     '60'
'01/01/2000'     '19:00'     '10'"

tc <- textConnection(txt)

data <- read.table(tc,header=FALSE,as.is=TRUE)
```

FUNCTION

```
fun <- function(data,cutoff=40){
 data_above <- 1L*(data$V3>cutoff)
 id_start <- which(diff(c(0L,data_above))==1)
 id_end <- which(diff(c(data_above,0L))== -1)
 res <- cbind(data[id_start,1:2],Duration=id_end-id_start+1)
 return(res)
}
```

RESULTS

```
fun(data)

          V1    V2 Duration
3 01/01/2000 10:00        4
9 01/01/2000 16:00        3
```

Comment: Thank you ever so much!! I spent all day just to figure out how to do this!  It works great! and also answers few question I had in my mind with how to use function in R. I am very new to R so really appreciate your help. Thanks again